# Is there any open source code available for simplification of tetrahedral mesh?

Tags: mesh

I am currently working on tetrahedral meshes and I want to downsample the mesh using techniques like Qslim but there is not much about tetrahedral meshes in the literature. I try to use it as a pooling layer in a neural network so computation cost is also important. I wonder if there is a open-source code available for this task.

Comment: Have you looked at [libigl](https://libigl.github.io/)? I know there is a fast Qslim implementation that you may be able to adapt to tetrahedral meshes.

Comment: The problem is, there is no straightforward pseudo-code that I can adapt. But thanks for your comment, I did look at it before but I will dig into it again.

Comment: Hi Mohammad, asking for us to find a resource is off topic (because we want the site to *be* that resource). I think your question would be easier to answer and more useful to other users if you describe the problem in more detail and ask for help with the specific problem or algorithm.

Comment: Hi Luser. I actually did describe it to some extent. I am in need of help for available source codes for tetrahedral mesh decimation like edge collapse. I cannot write the code from scratch.  I have seen many implementations for surface mesh decimation algorithms both in c++ and Python but not tetrahedral meshes. It is not that straightforward to adapt those techniques to tetrahedral meshes. Papers for tetrahedral mesh simplifications that I have seen so far do not have any code public available and there is no sign of pseudo-code either. I need some help how to tackle this problem.